# CSS Dropdown navigation - Dropdown appearing above parent link

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="header">
<div class="cont">
<div id="banner">

  <div id="nav">

  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.htm">home</a></li>

    <li><a href="work.html">Works»</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="paintings.html">Paintings</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Watercolour</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ink</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li style="

 "><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>
  <div id="greeting" style="
clear: both;
  ">
```

Navbar CSS (Full CSS can be found in the JSfiddle link below)

```
#nav
{ float:right;
position:relative;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
font-family: monospace, serif;
list-style-type: none;
height:150px;
}
#nav ul
{float: center;
clear: left;
font-family: monospace, serif;
list-style-type: none; 
text-align:center;
padding:0;
}
```

Example of my issue: http://jsfiddle.net/6n3WK/

As you can see from the jsfiddle link, when hovering over the "Works" link, the drop down appears above I've searched around and tried to fix it my self but no luck. I really appreciate the help and would like an explanation as to why it's going above the parent link, I had it working below previously and I changed some CSS and now it's all pete tong.
Thanks guys :)

Comment: Hi, I suggest you move your question first and then add your code. Please be as specific as possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#nav ul li:hover ul {
   display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
   text-align: center;
   visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your `li` elements a top `vertical-align`:

```css
#nav ul li {
    ...
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6n3WK/1/).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the positioning of `#nav ul li:hover ul` to `absolute`:

```
#nav ul li:hover ul {
    display:block;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
}
```

This will then position the `ul` in relation to the nearest `relative` positioned container, in this case your `#nav div`.

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6n3WK/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Not related with the positioning, but close the css statement on: `#nav ul li:hover ul li a:hover`, it might give you some trouble on the future

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position: relative` for `#nav ul li:hover ul`

Here is the demo 
http://jsfiddle.net/6n3WK/3/